# Relying on short-circuit evaluation instead of using the IF control structure

Tags: javascript, php

Examples of where I've started migrating to short-circuit evaluation:

**PHP**

```
$id=0;//initialized in case of no result
$r=mysql_query(SQL);
if($r && mysql_num_rows($r)>0){
  list($id)=mysql_fetch_row($r);
}
```

becomes

```
$id=0;
$r=mysql_query(SQL);
$r && mysql_num_rows($r)>0 && list($id)=mysql_fetch_row($r);
```

**JavaScript**

```
var Req=jQuery.ajax(OBJECT);
//Something has happened and now i want to abort if possible
if(Req && Req.abort){
  Req.abort();
}
```

becomes

```
var Req=jQuery.ajax(OBJECT);
//Something has happened and now i want to abort if possible
Req && Req.abort && Req.abort();
```

I'm familiar with the short `if` style of

```
if(Req && Req.abort) Req.abort();
```

but it feels clunkier than short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: This question may have been acceptable at the time it was asked, but it does not meet Code Review's question standards in 2015. Since you've asked about two isolated excerpts in two different languages that have nothing to do with each other besides the use of `&&`, this is a generic best-practices question, and therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an abuse of short-circuit evaluation.  It's not immediately obvious what the intent is.  Sure, i can *eventually* see that you're getting an ID, calling `Req.abort()`, whatever.  But i shouldn't have to decipher a line of code first to figure out what it does.
Conciseness never trumps readability in source code.  (Sure, minifying/packing JS has its benefits.  But you don't write packed/minified code; you start out with decent code and then run a tool on it.)

Since your intent is to do the one thing **if** the other stuff is true, the code should say that.

Comment: The added benefit is that when you see `if (x) { y }`, you can read `x` or `y` quickly and decide if you need to read the full statement or can skip it because it doesn't apply to your current task. With a single statement, you must read `x` plus enough of `y` to parse it. It makes scanning the code much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Also, jsbeautifier will format your code like this:

```
var Req = jQuery.ajax(OBJECT);  //<- Note the spaces around the equal sign
//Something has happened and now i want to abort if possible
if(Req && Req.abort)
{
  Req.abort();
}
```

Beyond, that lowerCamelCase should apply so `Req` -> `req` or even better `request` and `OBJECT` -> `object`, I am not too excited about either generic name, but I guess this is just a stub.

Furthermore it seems a bit paranoid to not trust `request` or `request.abort()`, I don't have enough code to see if this paranoia is justified.

Personally, I have taken to write this as :

```
( request && request.abort ) ? request.abort() : undefined;
```

or, with jQuery providing `noop`

```
( request && request.abort ) ? request.abort() : $.noop();
```

The `undefined` yells at my subconscious that I should really handle `request` or `request.abort` being falsey.

Furthermore, on `if` statements with 1 statement in the `true` block

Not acceptable:

```
if(Req && Req.abort) Req.abort();
```

Somewhat acceptable:

```
if(Req && Req.abort) 
  Req.abort();
```

Best practice:

```
if(Req && Req.abort){
  Req.abort();
}
```

Comment: If the coding standard were to allow single-statement blocks without braces, I would prefer to keep it in the same line to minimize the chance of adding a second statement without also adding braces. That said, I vastly prefer requiring braces in all cases for safety.

Comment: Hmmm, I never thought of it that way