# A platform-independent implementation of "which" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-system, portability

I like to know if there's anything that I may have missed in this implementation. The method tries to provide the absolute path of the binary or script which is likely to execute based on the provided path. I carefully based it from how `cmd.exe` chooses the file to execute. It intends to be platform-independent but so far it's only tested with an NT-based Windows and Linux. I don't plan to support legacy Windows or DOS that may not have `PATHEXT` just in case Ruby supports them.

You may also wonder why some declarations happen within a condition line but I find it hard seeing anything in the code like test flags that run even when they are not necessary so please just avoid talking about it or anything that's only about coding style or philosophy. Some may argue that it's not Ruby-like but it's simply functionally wrong or programmatically wrong to me. I also avoid significant redundant queries. Despite this I still balance efficiency and readability. I'm also strict to uniformity in coding style. Ruby may be an expressive language as some may say but I believe it's not restricted from showing *correct logic structure* and choosing not to compromise it for the sake of readability is an option.

```
module Bin
  def self.which(cmd)
    exts = (pathext = ENV['PATHEXT']) ? \
        pathext.split(';').select{ |e| e[0] == '.' } : []
    if (cmd[File::SEPARATOR] or (File::ALT_SEPARATOR and cmd[File::ALT_SEPARATOR])) \
    or (paths = ENV['PATH']).nil? \
    or (paths = paths.split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR).select{ |e| File.directory?(e) }).empty?
      if not exts.empty?
        return File.absolute_path(cmd) \
            if not (ext = File.extname(cmd)).empty? \
            and exts.any?{ |e| e.casecmp(ext) } \
            and File.file? cmd and File.executable? cmd
        exts.each do |ext|
          exe = "#{cmd}#{ext}"
          return File.absolute_path(exe) if File.file? exe and File.executable? exe
        end
      elsif File.file? cmd and File.executable? cmd
        return File.absolute_path(cmd)
      end
    elsif not exts.empty?
      has_valid_ext = (not (ext = File.extname(cmd)).empty? and exts.any?{ |e| e.casecmp(ext) })
      paths.unshift('.').each do |path|
        if has_valid_ext \
        and File.file? (exe = File.join(path, "#{cmd}")) \
        and File.executable? exe
          return File.absolute_path(exe)
        end
        exts.each do |ext|
          exe = File.join(path, "#{cmd}#{ext}")
          return File.absolute_path(exe) if File.file? exe and File.executable? exe
        end
      end
    else
      paths.each do |path|
        exe = File.join(path, cmd)
        return File.absolute_path(exe) if File.file? exe and File.executable? exe
      end
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Opinion:  If you need to use a bunch of backslashes to break up your lines, what you really need is shorter lines.  :P

Comment: Opinion 2: The method is too big, making it hard to follow. Consider breaking it up into well-named sub-methods.

Comment: BTW...If you're wondering why there aren't answers yet, it's probably because this code has pretty much failed at "balancing efficiency and readability".  I tried following it, but the constant reliance on short-circuiting, negative and side-effecting conditions drove me away after three or four attempts.  I'm not paid enough to try harder.  But you don't want to hear about readability, so there's not much to say.

Comment: @MarkThomas, cHao: Both your suggestions are elementary unfortunately I have to stick with the rules: (a) Correct logic structure must be maintained. i.e. flags must not be used as I don't want to check for something that may turn out to be unneeded later. (b) I can't create another function as I find it cleaner to encapsulate everything (for `Bin::which`) as a single function. I do modularize common functionalities when needed but this time I don't find it appropriate. Like I said it would be better if we just avoid anything about coding style or philosophy but thank you for anything.

Comment: @konsolebox, you are putting undue constraints on potential answers. "Correct logic structure" -- what does that even mean? Logic and structure are two different things. You don't want to "compromise it" for the sake of readability? Hmm. Also, you find it "cleaner" to create a single monolithic method, which flies in the face of idiomatic Ruby. You're not really giving anyone a chance to show you the realm of possibility here.

Comment: @MarkThomas I'm not compromising it just to get better readability. Anyhow I asked the question to know if there's something wrong with the functionality or implementation, not how the code was arranged. Debates about proper coding are not helpful. Try making a simpler (and significantly more readable) version of it if you like if you want to prove your point. I'm [unlikely a "monolithic" scripter or programmer](http://loader.sf.net/) but I'm strict to following necessary exceptions. Again, please avoid anything about coding style or philosophy. I would avoid it as well already next reply.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on Meta.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2453/are-questions-that-ask-not-to-offer-readability-style-structure-advice-on-top)

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back Rev 6 → 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see at least two issues, aside from the atrocious code style:

- `String#casecmp` returns an integer, much like `strcasecmp` does in C. But in Ruby, everything other than `false` and `nil` is truthy.  So if a `PATHEXT` environment variable is present and has at least one extension, and `cmd` has an extension, `has_valid_ext` will always be true -- regardless of whether `cmd`'s extension is valid.  The only thing keeping it from affecting results is the low chance of, say, `whatever.zip` being both executable and in the search path.
- Windows and Linux differ in how they handle the current directory when searching.  Windows checks it first before resorting to a path search, and Linux won't check it at all unless the path either includes it, or is *empty*.  If `$PATH` were set to `blah`, for example, Linux wouldn't even bother looking at `.`.

  Since you eliminate invalid directories *before* checking for emptiness, though, you don't catch the case where the path contains only inaccessible locations -- so you end up checking the CWD, making the result in Linux potentially different from what `which` would report.  Not sure how significant it is, since it's rather uncommon to have such a broken `PATH` variable...but it doesn't help.

Aside from that, there's a difference between "multi-platform" and "platform-independent".  This code can pretty much be considered the former (once it's fixed), but by definition is not the latter.  Anything that depends solely on system environment variables, has made assumptions about the platform that might not hold true.

For example, you assume that if `PATHEXT` exists, that (1) it has a certain significance, and (2) it is case insensitive.  You assume that iff there is a list of directories to search for files in, it will always be called `PATH`.  Without knowing what OS you're running in, neither assumption can be supported; at best, they're educated guesses.

Comment: Finally a real answer. That (the second issue) is exactly one I forgot and wasn't able to consider. As for the first one, I never used the method before and just found it somewhere. I should have checked the API doc too; or maybe I did but misread the returned value `nil` which actually is only returned when both strings are incompatible with their encoding format. Still it's odd that it went unnoticed in my tests.

Comment: And yes about that way of being multi-platform or platform-independent, I did chose to depend on the environment variables as I see it to be enough - more than relying on some other attributes for detecting the system. It's not worth adding sanity checks if someone decides to set the variable even if he/she is not in Windows. Also, I don't remember Windows ever being case-sensitive in filename, and seriously I don't think it will - being a descendant of DOS and all. Add: I would have to reconsider how I test things now because of the second issue.

Comment: @konsolebox: [NTFS is actually case-sensitive](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100625) for POSIX reasons.  Most subsystems of Windows just use it in its case-preserving mode by default.  (That can allegedly be changed, but of course changing it can break a bunch of other stuff. So it might not be worth caring about anyway.)  If the path includes a directory on a fully case-sensitive FS, though -- an NFS mount, for example -- i'm not sure whether Windows will pick `whatever.exe` if `PATHEXT` contains ".EXE".

Comment: Turns out your second point with reference to the solution was not completely correct since `paths.unshift('.')` would only happen if PATHEXT does have a valid value - a situation I had considered to not likely to occur in Linux. However thanks to it I had myself able to re-examine the behaviour in Cygwin and it turned out that I can't completely rely on PATHEXT. About other filesystems, I think it wouldn't be different. I believe it's not really about the filesystems, but how Windows read those filenames. Writing filenames can be case-sensitive but reading probably won't.

Comment: @konsolebox: `paths.unshift('.')` is not the only way to check the CWD.  What happens in the case where PATHEXT is null, PATH is "/nonexistent", and you're looking for "blah"?  The name has no separator, and `paths` won't be nil, but after your `.select`, it *will* be an empty array, so the first branch runs.  Since `not exts.empty?` is false, you'll end up at the `elsif File.file? cmd and File.executable? cmd` branch.  Which checks (and if it exists, returns) the file in the CWD.

Comment: You are correct. Looks like chained condition checking is no longer needed for this.

Comment: Anyway I think the code is already mature enough. Thank you very much for the help by the way. It was really helpful and the code is now much refined thanks to it.

Answer (score 8):

There's a lot going on here, so I'm going to put all my feedback in a list as I go through your code and put a new version of it with my suggested changes at the end.

Keep in mind that I'm not testing these changes and that the code I come up with may be broken or incorrect. It's simply the result of me going through this and changing things to bring them up to a level of quality I'd expect within a codebase I was responsible for.

### Feedback

- I used the `extend self` shorthand/pattern to declare all methods within
  the bin module as class methods. I generally don't use this too much unless
  I'm working on singleton classes/modules like the one you're provided us.
- There are a lot of logical checks here that could easily be broken out into
  private methods on the `Bin` module. doing so lets you break up many of the
  if/else checks into their own contexts.
- I had trouble reading variables like 'pathext' thinking it was 'path text',
  so I renamed such variables to include underscores to help me avoid skimming
  through words thinking they meant or referred to things they did not.
- I like to avoid implicitly referencing global or environment variables
  within the body of a method. The main motivation for this is that by
  allowing arbitrary strings within the input for methods like
  `Bin.extensions`, I'm now able to more easily test the method by providing
  it input without needing to resort to polluting global state within
  my unit tests.
- Avoid the keywords 'and' and 'or' unless you are VERY sure you need them.
  The operator precedence for these keywords is LOWER than their short-hand
  equivalents '&&' and '||'. Using these without understanding this little
  fact can lead to surprising behavior.
- I saw a few places where you were using `.select { ... }.empty?` to check
  if any or all items in the select block passed a test. The `Enumerable`
  module within the ruby standard library has you covered here:
  use `.any?`, `all?`, or `.none?` to do similar tests if all you need is a
  boolean result.
- Following up on my last point, you can call methods like `.any?` on
  without a block and they will implicitly test the truthyness of a value;
  ie: `[1,2].any?` is equivalent to `[1,2].any? { |num| num ? true : false }`
- Avoid constructs like `if not`; ruby provided the `unless` keyword
  for negative assertions. Use it.
- Document your methods thoroughly, comment on complex bits of code,
  and explain any design decisions that are significant to your code.
  I don't trust myself to remember my thought process for code
  I wrote an hour ago, let alone that of someone who wrote something
  long, long ago in a place far, far away.

  I'm personally a fan of [YARD](http://yardoc.org/) for documentation of ruby code, but the tools
  you use for this (if any) are unimportant so long as the poor sod who comes
  after you has some help figuring out what's going on. You'll feel even
  better about making such efforts when that poor sod will probably be you.

### Revised Code

```
# `Bin.which` is (hopefully) a operating system agnostic implementation of
# Linux's `which` command.
module Bin
  extend self

  private

  # All paths availble in `ENV['PATH']` as an array
  # @return [Array<String>] an array of paths
  def paths
    ENV['PATH'] ? ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR) : []
  end

  # Returns all files within a string that contain a '.'
  #
  # @param path_ext [String] a semicolon delimited string of valid filename
  #                          extensions for executables
  # @return [Array<String>] an array containing valid executable file extensions
  # @example
  #   extensions('file1.txt; fizzbuzz ; file3.jpg')
  #   # => ['file1.txt', 'file3.jpg']
  def extensions(path_ext = ENV['PATHEXT'])
    return [] unless path_ext # no-op if PATHEXT is not set/present
    path_ext.split(';').select { |segment| segment[0] == '.' }
  end

  # Determine if the provided string appears to be a filename or a directory
  #
  # @param string [String] a file path or filename
  # @return [Boolean]
  def directory?(path)
    if path[File::SEPARATOR] || File::ALT_SEPARATOR && path[File::ALT_SEPARATOR]
      return true

    else
      paths.any? { |p| File.directory?(p) }
    end
  end

  # Determine if the provided string is an known file extension for executable
  # files on this system.
  #
  # @param ext [String] a file extension
  # @return [Boolean]
  def executable_file_extension?(ext)
    return false if ext.empty?
    extensions.any? { |extension| extension.casecmp(ext) }
  end

  # Given a path to a file, determine if the provided path leads to a
  # file with a known executable file extension
  #
  # @param path [String] the path to a file
  def path_with_executable_file_extension?(path)
    ext = File.extname(path)

    return false if ext.empty?
    executable_file_extension?(ext)
  end

  # Given a path, determine if the path is that of an executable file.
  #
  # If `dir` is provided, assume that the provided path is relative to `dir`
  # and attempt to find an executable file there.
  #
  # @param filename [String] the path to a file
  # @param dir [String] a directory within which to find `filename`
  # @return [Boolean]
  #
  # @example Basic usage
  #   executable_file?('/bin/sh') #=> true
  #
  # @example Finding an executable within a directory
  #   executable_file?('sh', '/usr/local') #=> false
  #   executable_file?('sh', '/bin') #=> true
  def executable_file?(filename, dir = nil)
    path = File.join(dir, filename) if dir
    path ||= filename

    File.file?(path) && File.executable?(path)
  end

  public

  # Platform independent implementation of the linux `which` command
  # @param cmd [String] The name of a command to find
  # @return [String, Nil] Returns the aboslute path to the desired command
  #                       or `nil` if the command could not be found
  # @example
  #   which('vim') # => '/usr/local/bin/vim'
  #   which('/usr/local/bin/vim') # => '/usr/local/bin/vim'
  #   which('foobar') # => nil
  def which(cmd)
    # Check to see if there is an executable file that shares the name
    # of a directory at the same path (ie: `/foo/bar/` and `/foo/bar.exe`)
    if directory?(cmd)
      if extensions.any?
        if path_with_executable_file_extension?(cmd) && executable_file?(cmd)
          return File.absolute_path(cmd)
        end

        extensions.each do |extension|
          exe = format('%s%s', cmd, extension)
          return File.absolute_path(exe) if executable_file?(cmd)
        end

      elsif executable_file?(cmd)
        return File.absolute_path(cmd)
      end

    # Search for the provided command within all
    # of the designated PATH locations
    elsif extensions.any?
      paths.delete_if { |path| path == '.' }.each do |path|
        if path_with_executable_file_extension?(cmd) && executable_file?(cmd, path)
          return File.absolute_path File.join(path, cmd.to_s)
        end

        extensions.each do |extension|
          exe = File.join(path, format('%s%s', cmd, extension))
          return File.absolute_path(exe) if executable_file?(exe)
        end
      end

    else
      paths.each do |path|
        exe = File.join(path, cmd)
        return File.absolute_path(exe) if executable_file?(exe)
      end
    end

    nil
  end
end
```

Comment: There goes the redundancy I'm trying to avoid. Now you're querying and processing `ENV['PATH']` more than once. Also, the first condition doesn't check if the argument is a directory. It checks if it's not in plain form i.e. it is in the form of a path (having a directory part) may it be relative or absolute path. By the way, using `unless` over `if not` is good, but not when using it along with `elsif`. Nevertheless thank you for the answer. Using `.any?` over `not x.empty?` should be considered.

Comment: I also have to say this: `&&` and `||` is not always usable for chained conditions along `if` since `&&` has higher precedence than `||` whereas `and` and `or` has the same. If you've been into shell scripting, you'd understand the significance of it. Now I understand why many would not understand my code or finds it alien since such useful practice is not known or is rejected by many that they are forced to have such simple statements to be encapsulated along functions or processed somewhere before it with a flag.

Comment: @konsolebox: If you want a shell script, write a shell script. Ruby isn't Bash; it has its own fundamental differences and strengths that you're just Blub'ing your way past.

Comment: @cHao These practices you claim to be Ruby aren't officially Ruby either. And I only gave that as an example reference. Just forget about shell scripting then. You can do that in other languages not just Bash nor Ruby. And I hope there's something less trivial you can say about it. I'm actually surprised that you have said something like that.

Comment: *I saw a few places where you were using .select { ... }.empty? to check if any or all items in the select block passed a test. The Enumerable module within the ruby standard library has you covered here: use .any?, all?, or .none? to do similar tests if all you need is a boolean result.* -> This point missed something: `(paths = paths.split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR).select{ |e| File.directory?(e) }).empty?` doesn't only test it if it's empty, but also stores the found elements on `paths`.

Comment: @konsolebox: I have no idea why you're surprised.  [I've gone on record](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5982/1478) calling out abuse very much like that.  Every language that supports chaining conditionals like that has a better way of handling it.  Well, ok, maybe not Bash.  But every useful language.  :)

Comment: @cHao You'd be surprised how far Bash can do things in some fields way easier more than Ruby or any other language. Sometimes it even gets more efficient being the master of all binary tools. It's even more portable sometimes. And I'm surprised simply because it's obvious or a very common reply: *If you want a shell script, write a shell script. Ruby isn't Bash*. Just like how people say: *If you want to make things faster or more efficient, don't use Bash or Ruby*. Seriously, is that the only rationale to it?.

Comment: Chaining conditionals as some may think bizarre are useful and easy as C to those who are used to it, but not to conservative parties who reject those practices and think of it as evil. This *better way of handling it* is choosable but not always beneficial and has drawbacks just as how the example revised code above shows it: redundancy and doing advanced checking when not necessary. You are also forced to add another function just to prevent it and encapsulate recursive `if` statements which would have made the code more cluttered inside a single method. Things actually get more difficult.

Comment: If not for the documentation comments which are evenly helpful if added to my code (something you optionally add in the final stages, or else you'd be forced to change it too for every significant revision adding more work), the revised code above would not really have significant gain when it comes to readability over less usage of remotely encapsulated codes, runtime efficiency (you can exclude this if you like), and perhaps significant need to add more documentation to them (every other function).

Comment: @konsolebox: I agree that the methodizing here isn't overly helpful; it kinda seems to add complexity.  There's a lot to be said, though, for breaking up decisions into smaller chunks, and particularly for giving intermediate results useful names -- and not just the ones you plan to use, but also the non-trivial ones.  If you'd given a name like `has_dir` to `cmd[File::SEPARATOR] or (File::ALT_SEPARATOR and cmd[File::ALT_SEPARATOR])`, for example, you probably wouldn't have to correct someone on what it means.  (BTW, you could also say that more simply as `File.basename(cmd) != cmd`.)

Comment: @konsolebox: I wouldn't be surprised about what Bash can do.  I was mostly kidding with the "useful" bit; i just knew it'd get a bit of a rise out of you.  :)  I know it's better at some things.  But just like any other programming language, its true power only really comes through when you stop speaking it like a foreigner and adopt its particular idioms.  If i were writing a Bash script as if it were Ruby or C, you'd almost certainly tell me how hideously overcomplicated it is, and suggest "cleaner", more idiomatic solutions.

Comment: @cHao I'm not community-oriented and I don't care about idiomatic solutions. I always look at what's more appropriate to me. Idiomatic solutions most of the time is a product of the community (not even necessarily a practice of the language itself), and the community is not always right. Btw, I also do that in C, and probably would also do in any language that's capable of it. I'd rather have chained conditions than have nested `if`'s or additional functions which most of the time is only referenced by a single caller.

Comment: @konsolebox: Whether you're "community-oriented" or not, you're dealing with the community.  Telling them "screw how you'd do it; i prefer *correct logic structure*" is *extremely* counter-productive.  Even if they don't take it as an insult (which many will) and either ignore you or tell you to piss off (which many will), you make it more difficult even for the ones who decided to try and help.